# Index control with V-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My problem is very dumb… I’m a beginner.
So I have a `v-for` displaying a list of elements, if one is pressed it gets **SELECTED**.

```
<div v-for="(name) in categories" class="item">
    <span @click="categorySelected(name)"
        {{ name }}  
    </span>
</div>
```

I have a method that saves this status like this:

```
categorySelected (category) {
    this.selectedCategory = category
    this.$emit('category-selected', category)
},
```

I would like to have a button in the same `<span>`, that when pressed makes the next element in the array the **SELECTED** one, by having a function similar to the one above, something like this:

```
<div @click="nextCategory(name)"> Next </div>
```

The problem is that I’m passing the (name) of the current item to the method, I’m not sure how to pass the values of the next item. Any help?

Comment: could you try and develop the _I would like to have a button, that when pressed makes the next element in the array the SELECTED one, by having a function similar to the one above, something like this:_? Would this mean that you want user to be able to select item in `categories`? (eg: [a, b, c, d], if user click on `b` it will select `c`). Rather than answering these questions, you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57475632/edit) to clarify it :)

Comment: You are right i’m editing ti clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your mark up will look something like this, you can use an index.

```
<div v-for="(name, index) in categories" class="item">
    <span @click="categorySelected(name)"
        {{ name }}  
    </span>
    <div @click="selectNextCategory(index + 1)"> Next </div>
</div>
```

You can look up the category by index

```
selectNextCategory(index) {
    this.selectedCategory = this.categories[index]
    this.$emit('category-selected', this.selectedCategory)
}
```

Or re-use

```
selectNextCategory(index) {
    this.categorySelected(this.categories[index]);
}
```

**Update**

To guard against the last item array out of bounds exception you can do ether or both of the following:

Stop displaying the next button with `v-if`. 
`<div v-if="(index + 1) < categories.length" @click="selectNextCategory(index + 1)"> Next </div>`

Or prevent the selection of next category:

```
selectNextCategory(index) {
    if(index < this.categories.length) {
        this.categorySelected(this.categories[index]);
    }
}
```

**Computed List**

You can created a computed list with the current and next item names.

```
computed: {
   Categories() {
       return this.categories.map((c, index) => {
           var nextIndex = index + 1;
           return {
               current: c,
               next: nextIndex < this.categories.length 
                   ? this.categories[nextIndex]
                   : null
           }
       })
   }
}
```

Now you can make a mark up like this using this list:

```
<div v-for="c in Categories" class="item">
    <span @click="categorySelected(c.current)"
        {{ c.current }}  
    </span>
    <div v-if="c.next" @click="categorySelected(c.next)"> Next </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your assumption is right, there is one last error to handle, the selection of a category out of array bounds (click on `selectNextCategory` for the last one).

Comment: Thanks, but i’m not sure if this will work, since i’ve tried to set an index, like this    key:name.    But it seems that the key becomes a property of each item, so it didn’t seem to work as an array index to use as argument, but i will try, thanks!

Comment: @danieledep Sorry that comment doesn't make much sense. I have however updated the answer.

Comment: Yea i need to Study more, in the meantime thank you for your detailed answer!